# How to override a method that is not designed for extension

Tags: java, checkstyle

Below is a very simple code in Java.

The problem is in the class **SC** as comments shows. The problem can be easily fixed by removing the **final** modifier in class **C**, but it will raise a warning in **Checkstyle plugin** saying *Method 'm' is not designed for extension - needs to be abstract, final or empty.*

**What is the best design practice here that I should follow?**

```
public interface I {
    public void m();
}

public class C implements I {
    @Override
    public final void m() {
        // some code
    }
}

public class SC extends C {
    @Override
    public final void m(){
        // error message saying "Cannot override the final method from C"
    } 
}
```

Comment: The best solution is to remove `final` modifier in `C`. Another may be having a method `m2` in `SC` that calls `m` from `C` but looks like a code smell and should be avoided.

Comment: By the way, you should provide a better example for `m` in order to understand why checkstyle raises that warning for it if it can be overridden.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks for the comment. My example resembles the actual code pretty closely. I assumed that Checkstyle raises the warning for all methods with "@Override" annotation, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I would say the problem is not in your design but in your rules on checkstyle.

Comment: The problem may well be in the design - we have no idea what these classes and interfaces are for. If C hasn't really been *designed* for inheritance, there may well be significant problems in extending it. Could you use composition instead?

Comment: Removing `final` in both `C` and `SC` should produce correct code. That warning you quote does not sound right. Is it produced by `C.m()` or by `SC.m()`?

Comment: @SnakE It seems that the warning appears when m() in C is not implement nor abstract. Probably since that means that it might not have an implementation anywhere.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure, I can use composition instead. Just wondering, does this mean that whenever a class implements an interface, it should never be extended? Since once this class is extended, the Checkstyle warning will occur.

Comment: @Skyline: Well *that* part is just Checkstyle... it's not an unreasonable guideline to aim for - and certainly to understand - but I wouldn't say I follow that 100%.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for this. My earlier comment is not entirely correct. I should have said: If a class implements an interface, its subclasses should never override the methods in the interface. I guess it makes sense anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If `m()` in C is final, you cannot override it. Since class C implements from interface I, it *has* to implement all I's methods, that is the way an interface contract is designed.
Note that C does not know of SC. Thus, you should remove final in C and implement `m()` in C. The implementation *could*  even be blank, depending on what kind of task C is supposed to perform. There is no problem overriding an already existing method (`m()`) from C in SC.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does this mean that I should ignore the Checkstyle warning? Maybe I should turn this warning off completely because of false alarms like this?

Comment: @Skyline I am not completely sure what the C class should do. If it is supposed to be a parent class supplying child classes with methods the child classes need to implement I would make C abstract and keep the Checkstyle. If it only happens to be that SC extends C (to perform something extra) I would implement the method in C (thus the warning should be gone) and then let SC call super.m(); TLDR: I would reconsider the design and relation between C and SC and keep the Checkstyle :)